# Select Statement Joining Two Tables With Two Keys

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to get a correct record that shows the sum of values in this activities table and in addition it requires me to have an absolute match with both key values.

Heres a rough sketchup of what I'm trying to do...

[image]

With that in mind I the values of UserID will likely repeat as I have 3 brands.

So a 1 for F, 1 for M, 1 for J for each brand value.

The stored procedure that I had currently came up with is like this...

```
Select datename(month, A.ActivityTime), U.UserID, U.FirstName, U.LastName, Sum(A.Steps) as [Total Steps], Sum(A.Miles) as [Total Miles], Sum(A.MinutesActive) as [Total Minutes]
from Tracker.Activities as A join Tracker.Users as U on (U.BrandID = A.BrandID) and (U.UserID = A.UserID)
where Month(ActivityTime) = @month
group by datename(month, A.ActivityTime), U.FirstName, U.LastName, U.UserID
order by [Total Miles] desc
```

And should display a table that shows a total for each Column separated by UserID and BrandID.

Here is a picture of the two tables that I am pulling information from for reference.

[image]

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Whats your problem? Do you need to group by Brand ID too?